# Protocol error (Network.deleteCookies): Invalid parameters Failed to deserialize params.name - BINDINGS: mandatory field missing at position X

Tags: node.js, cookies, puppeteer, setcookie

Hello i'm trying to set some cookies for puppeteer so i don't have to login each time i launch my app. But i can't set it for some stupid reason, it just throws at me the same error no matter what i do.

Here's what i've tried:

```
await main_page.setExtraHTTPHeaders({
      'Cookie': process.env.SECRETCOOKIE
  });
```

Issue is that it only works on the initial request and for the others it doesn't set cookie and thus i'm still unauthorized. `main_page.on('request')` doesn't work properly.

Here's my cookie:

```
[
  {
    name: '29bd58896df4f6b1cffb2262ba9ede2a',
    value: '2717086f555f480cdfsf5b0671ba9ddb131aff624a:4:{i:0;s:5:"24544";i:1;s:22:"efeefefsfsfsdfsdf";i:2;i:604800;i:3;a:1:{s:5:"title";s:22:"sfdsfsdfsdfsdfsdf";}}'
  },
  { name: 'dffsfsfs', value: 'b5rknd0edbnu9vmlofhh0cc7j2' }
]
```

Which i parsed using `cookie.parse` (it was initially a string)

```
const tr = transformCookies(cookie.parse(process.env.SECRETCOOKIE));
```

And transformed using mapping

```
function transformCookies(cookieObj)
{
    return Object.keys(cookieObj).map(key => {
        const url = new URL(process.env.MAIN_URL)
        return {
            name: key,
            value: cookieObj[key],
            // domain: url.host,
            // path: '/',
        }
    });
}
```

(i've tried with host and domain, it still doesn't work)

And i also tried passing raw cookies from `cookie.parse` without transformation to the setCookie it still doesn't work.
And so the error is this:

**ProtocolError: Protocol error (Network.deleteCookies): Invalid parameters Failed to deserialize params.name - BINDINGS: mandatory field missing at position 246**
at <instance_members_initializer> (D:\Desktop\rozparamchanger\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\Connection.js:49:14)
at new Callback (D:\Desktop\rozparamchanger\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\Connection.js:53:16)
at CallbackRegistry.create (D:\Desktop\rozparamchanger\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\Connection.js:93:26)
at Connection._rawSend (D:\Desktop\rozparamchanger\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\Connection.js:207:26)
at CDPSessionImpl.send (D:\Desktop\rozparamchanger\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\Connection.js:433:33)
at CDPPage.deleteCookie (D:\Desktop\rozparamchanger\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\Page.js:464:32)
at CDPPage.setCookie (D:\Desktop\rozparamchanger\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\Page.js:479:20)
at D:\Desktop\rozparamchanger\index.js:25:13

I've tried googling question and not found any answer besides [this](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/7029#issuecomment-813761769), but when i try to do as the answer said i just get another error: **ProtocolError: Protocol error (Network.setCookies): Invalid cookie fields**

I also tried doing something like this:

```
await main_page.setCookie([{
        name:process.env.SCNAME_1,
        value: process.env.SCVAL_1,
    },{
        name:process.env.SCNAME_2,
        value:process.env.SCVAL_2,
    }])
```

But that gives me the same error over and over, i checked storage in chrome dev tools and it successfully set first cookie, but not the other, i don't know why it doesn't set it, maybe that's because of forbidden symbols, but i've tried urlEncoding and urlDecoding them, it still gives me an error, just at a different position.